# Identifying abusive users in a Loyalty rewards program

Tags: statistics, data-science

Assume you have a loyalty rewards program, where every user who makes a purchase earns 200% of their order amount as reward points and when users return the item - the 200% points based on the current price of the product are deducted. We suspect some users have realized a gateway where they buy the product at full price but return when it is at discounted price so they keep the net difference in points (the refund always refunds full order amount). If user does this accidentally or if the impact is less than 5000 reward points then business wants to ignore but identify anyone who is abusing this - how will you identify such users based on last 6 months of order and refund data. How will you identify this in real time as new orders/refunds are processed.

Comment: How to you store buy/sell events? Do you have a database? If yes what is the data model?

Comment: I do not have real-time data. It was a kind of case study in Machine Learning. They just wanted to know how you approach the problem.